# Paperspace: Docker pull private image

Tags: docker, security, yaml, pull

I'd like to pull a private image from Docker Hub in Paperspace Deployment.

It uses a yaml file, in which the command can overwrite the default pull command.

This is the yaml file:

```
image: image_name/ref
port: xxxx
command:
  - docker login -u 'docker_user' -p 'docker_password'
  - docker pull image_name/ref:latest
resources:
  replicas: 1
  instanceType: C4
```

I have the following error:

```
Node State: errored
Error: An error occurred when pulling image:[image_name/ref] from deployment
```

Note: the commands

```
  - docker login -u 'docker_user' -p 'docker_password'
  - docker pull image_name/ref:latest
```

Work from my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is a container menu to specify user and password (see team settings in the top right menu -> containers).

Then you have to use the option "containerRegistry" to pull the image properly:
image: image_name/ref
containerRegistry: name_in_paperspace
port: 5000
resources:
replicas: 1
instanceType: C4

Everything is explained in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPQ7AKwNlWU

Answer (score 1):

`command` in `docker-compose.yaml` is used to:

> overrides the default command declared by the container image

Not `overwrite the default pull command` as what you thought.

So, to let `docker-compose` to pull a private docker image, you need to do a initial `docker login` before run compose, detail see [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/).

Comment: thank you atline: how can I apply the login before the image pull in the yaml file?

Comment: I think you can't do it in docker-compose.yaml, you could just execute somthing like next in shell: `cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin` before you run your `docker-compose`

Comment: In fact, there is a solution specific to paperspace: you have to register a private container before deploying it. I'll add the answer just in case other people have the same issue.